# How do you add superscript to a label in Xamarin Forms using Xaml

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How do you add superscript to a label in Xamarin Forms using Xaml.  Specifically, I would like to add a TM superscript for trademark.

Comment: unicode to the rescue - `&#8482;`

Comment: Sweet!  I actually had thought of that, but sadly I failed to add the semi-colon at the end so the compiler wasn't happy.  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Chris mentioned in the comment you can use the unicode character `&#8482;` (™)

You should use the CustomeRenderer if you want to do anything complex

Answer (score 2):

Set the `Label`'s `TextType` property to `Html`.

For example, to produce: x<sup>2</sup> + y

In XAML:

```
<Label Text="x&lt;sup&gt;&lt;small&gt;2&lt;/small&gt;&lt;/sup&gt; + y" TextType="Html"/>
```

or

```
<Label TextType="Html">
    <![CDATA[
    x<sup><small>2</small></sup> + y
    ]]>
</Label>
```

In C#:

```
Label myLabel=new Label{TextType=TextType.Html,Text="x<sup><small>2</small></sup> + y"}
```

Note that the <small> tag is optional.

For more information, see the "Display HTML" section of the `Label` documentation: [Xamarin.Forms Label: Display HTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label#display-html)