# add superscript to a label in Xamarin Forms using Xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, superscript

How do you add superscript to a label in Xamarin Forms using Xaml. Specifically, I would like to add a "$"  superscript for trademark.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39472883/5228202

Answer (score 1):

You could set the **StringFormat** of the label

```
<Label Text="{Binding xxx,StringFormat='The price is ${0:C2}'}" />
```

Comment: [Should I answer duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844)

Comment: yes @Cfun, i am unable to find for $ sign

Comment: &#x24; html code ?